# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' from user input

Tags: python, ide

I'm running python 3 in the default IDE.

Here is my code:

```py
def print_():
    f = open("height.txt","r")
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
    f.close()
    main()


def main():     
    name = str(input("What is your name?"))
    data = int(input("How tall are you? (CM)"))

    if data.isdigit() == True:
        print("\n")

    elif data.isdigit() == False:
        print("Must be a number!")
        main()


    # a+ is read only mode
    f = open("height.txt","a+")
    f.write(name)
    f.write(str(data))
    f.write("cm, ")
    f.close()

    data_1 = str(input("1 = View Contents. Other = Quit"))
    if data_1 == '1':
        print_()

    else:
        print("Exiting")

main()
```

Comment: My error is -     if data.isdigit() == True:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: Seems like this program may have issues with recursion. You call the main function if the data is not an int and then write to height.txt. I think you want to kill the function after the call to main... so. print("must be a number") main() return

Comment: Okay, I understand! Thank-you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to check `isdigit()` on data you already casted to int.  Read it in as a `str` then cast it once you've checked it's a digit:

```
def main():     
    name = str(input("What is your name?"))
    data = str(input("How tall are you? (CM)"))

    while !data.isdigit():
        print("Must be a number!")
        data = str(input("How tall are you? (CM)"))
        print("\n")

    data = int(data)
    print("\n")
```

this loop will continue to ask for an int until provided with one, then cast it as int

Comment: Okay, i see. So i need to set it to a string to check if its a digit. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Exactly, and `int` has no `isdigit()` method, it must be a string.  If you don't check first, trying to cast a string as `int` could throw an exception.  GLHF bro

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that isdigit operates on a string; however you cast the data object to an int already: data = int(input("How tall are you? (CM)")). You should let the data be a string if you want to use the isdigit function. data = str(input("..."))